# IntelliJ CE icon shows "EAP" when using stable update channel

Tags: intellij-idea, icons, beta

**UPDATE**

The bug mentioned in @s0xzwasd's answer has now been fixed in Ij 2020.3.01

**Original**

---

Today I updated to Intellij CE 2020.3 (IC-203.5981.155), and the icon in my dock displays like so:

[image: Dock logo]

I would assume EAP stands for Early Access Program, but have I chosen (or rather chosen not to leave) the stable update channel, and have never had an EA version of Intellij or any Jetbrains IDE on my computer. Why does the icon display like it does?

More info:

[image: Update info]

[image: Exit confirmation shows EAP in icon]

I am using a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 (19H15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow [IDEA-256564](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256564) to stay updated. It's already fixed and should be available in the next update.